Create a .NET 9 Blazor project with Individual Accounts crashes on registrationn
I'm intrigued in creating a new project with Blazor on .NET 9. In this project, I want to add the Authentication Type as "Individual Accounts". For that, I create a new project with the following values:

Framework: .NET 9
Authentication type: individual accounts
Interactive render mode: auto


The project was created successfully and I ran the update-database to create the ASP.NET database. When I run the application and register a new user, I get this error:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException: 'Exception_WasThrown'


I don't understand how to avoid this error.
Update
There is an issue open on GitHub. At the moment, there is no workaround.

The title of your question says it's .net8 but in the question text you're writing about .net9. What is correct?

Sorry, my bad, NET9

What happens when you just press F5 (continue), or run the app without debugging?

Thsi is not a bug. This is a known issue. Please see the comment above the line that has the exception. It explains that this is the expected behavior. However, Microsoft plans to address this in a future release: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/58573

Sorry, this PR doesn't seem related to this issue

@Enrico I double checked yes that is the correct PR. You will see in the image from the OP that the exception is being thrown on navigation and that is what the pr resolves.
